# FileMaker + Ruby + HTML + eBay: Any way to upload listings as HTML?

Tags: html, ruby, filemaker, ebay-design-templates

I work for a small business that does a lot of commerce via eBay. Right now, we have a pretty large database (in FileMaker), and our current method for getting newly-entered items from the database to eBay involves entering them manually, line-by-line, through a browser window into Auctiva. This is an extremely time-consuming process, and I've been tasked with automating it, if possible I've already written a good bit of code in Ruby to parse tab-delimited FileMaker exports into pretty much whatever I want, so I was wondering if there was some way to upload static HTML directly into an eBay listing. If so, I could just snag a spiffy HTML template from [oswd](http://owsd.org), modify it, and modify the code I've already written to handle injecting the pertinent info directly into the document, then just upload that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do whatever with the product data, and have all the data necessary to make a listing, you can use the eBay API.

http://developer.ebay.com/products/trading/

has a HTTP POST based submission handler so you can use any http client you want (Net::HTTP, HTTP party, Curb etc) and post your listings that way.